# Photo post not showing on Tumblr Site

Tags: html, tumblr

For some reason the photo that I've posted on my Tumblr site is not showing up?. Any ideas would be helpful sense I can't get it to display on screen?.

```
{block:HighRes}
                                        <div id="hoc_img_0" class="img_target post photo">

                                                <img width="370px" height="555px" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes},{PhotoWidth-370},{PhotoHeight-555}"/>
                                                <div class="footer_nav">
                                                    <div id="icons" class="center_content2">
                                                        <a class="reblog_ico" href="http://www.tumblr.com" target="_blank"></a> 
                                                        <a class="like_ico" href="http://www.tumblr.com"></a> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                        </div>
                                        {/block:HighRes}
```

**I've included the new html which only displays one photo post and not the other?.**

```
 {block:Photo}
                                        <div id="hoc_img_0" class="img_target">
                                                    {block:Post2}
                                                    <img width="370px" height="555px" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                                                    {/block:Post2}
                                                <div class="footer_nav">
                                                    <div id="icons" class="center_content2">
                                                        {block:NotReblog} 
                                                        <a class="reblog_ico" href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank"></a> 
                                                        {/block:NotReblog}

                                                        <a class="like like_ico" href="#" data-postid="{PostID}" data-oauth="{ReblogURL}"></a> 

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                      {/block:Photo}
                                       {block:Photo}
                                        <div id="hoc_img_1" class="img_target">

                                                {block:Post1}
                                                <img width="370px" height="555px" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                                                {/block:Post1}
                                                <div class="footer_nav">
                                                    <div id="icons" class="center_content2">
                                                        {block:NotReblog} 
                                                        <a class="reblog_ico" href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank"></a> 
                                                        {/block:NotReblog}
                                                    <a class="like like_ico" href="#" data-postid="{PostID}" data-oauth="{ReblogURL}"></a> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                       {/block:Photo}
```

Thanks,

- Abel

Comment: Wait, is this a problem with the user experience on the tumblr site, or is this a programming question? It looks very much like a question why your upload is not showing, which is not what this site is for.

Comment: Hi yes this is a programming question, I've included my block statements and variables from this url. http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#introduction

Comment: Can you post a link to the tumblr?

Comment: 1) Is the image you have uploaded definitely high resolution? It has to be over 500px wide. 2) You wrapped your code above in the `{block:Posts}` theme operator to start the post logic?

Comment: I figured it out but now my issue is to display multiple posts one shows and not the other. I've updated my post above, please see the  mark-up?.

Comment: For both your questions, please add a link to a live example.

Comment: Sorry its work related, but I managed to figure it out it was how I began and ended my photo posts with variable blocks. I've updated my post for future reference for anybody out there in the future.